# How can I change the location for backup - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I have my database in disk C: , and also the default folder for backup is in disk C. I need to change location for database backup from C: to D:.
How to do that?!

Comment: Using `rman`, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

That should be pretty simple. You should do this from rman. Also run a "show all;" to see how your backups are configured.

```
CONNECT TARGET /
SHOW ALL;
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'D:\rman_backup\%d_%Y_%M_%D_%t_%s_%c_%p';
```